# Can't access Vagrant Apache after Windows 10 update

Tags: apache, vagrant, virtualbox, windows-10, puphpet

Something weird happened with my Vagrant Box after last bigger update of Windows 10. 
After the reboot I tried to run my box. Everything went well until I've tried to reach my website through the browser.
It take a wile and I am getting "The connection has timed out" error.
Box is based on Ubuntu generated with puphpet and before the update everything worked perfectly fine.
SSH is working ok. Can ping host from guest. File synchronization works too. Apache is running. No errors in logs.
The only thing that doesn't work is access to apache server. Cannot connect to DB server via MySQL Workbench too.

I've already wasted many hours trying to fix it.

What I've already tried:
- Searching Google
- Vagrant and VirtualBox update and re installation
- changing IP address
- creating new box from scratch with different IP - the result is the same

```
vagrantfile:
target: local
vm:
    box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
    box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
    hostname: ecoopony2
    memory: '512'
    cpus: '1'
    chosen_provider: virtualbox
    network:
        private_network: 192.168.56.102
        forwarded_port:
            vflnp_ejmowjjnv12t:
                host: '9376'
                guest: '22'
    post_up_message: ''
    provider:
        virtualbox:
            modifyvm:
                natdnshostresolver1: 'on'
            showgui: '0'
        vmware:
            numvcpus: 1
        parallels:
            cpus: 1
    provision:
        puppet:
            manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
            module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
            options:
                - '--verbose'
                - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
    synced_folder:
        vflsf_bfsxjusk9wbc:
            source: ./www/
            target: /var/www/
            sync_type: nfs
            smb:
                smb_host: ''
                smb_username:
                smb_password:
            rsync:
                args:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--archive'
                    - '-z'
                exclude:
                    - .vagrant/
                    - .git/
                auto: 'true'
            owner: www-data
            group: www-data
    usable_port_range:
        start: 10200
        stop: 10500
ssh:
    host: null
    port: null
    private_key_path: null
    username: vagrant
    guest_port: null
    keep_alive: true
    forward_agent: false
    forward_x11: false
    shell: 'bash -l'
    insert_key: false
vagrant:
    host: detect
server:
install: '1'
packages:
    - vim
users_groups:
   install: '1'
   groups: {  }
   users: {  }
locale:
install: '1'
settings:
    default_locale: ''
    locales:
        - en_GB.UTF-8
        - en_US.UTF-8
        - pl_PL.UTF-8
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
        proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
        proxy_send_timeout: 600s
        proxy_read_timeout: 600s
        names_hash_bucket_size: 128
    upstreams: {  }
vhosts:
    nxv_pclanhbf5fsf:
        server_name: awesome.dev
        server_aliases:
            - www.awesome.dev
        www_root: /var/www/awesome
        listen_port: '80'
        index_files:
            - index.html
            - index.htm
            - index.php
        client_max_body_size: 1m
        ssl: '0'
        ssl_cert: ''
        ssl_key: ''
        ssl_port: '443'
        ssl_protocols: ''
        ssl_ciphers: ''
        rewrite_to_https: '1'
        spdy: '1'
        locations:
            nxvl_zwurha5mno40:
                location: /
                autoindex: 'off'
                internal: 'false'
                try_files:
                    - $uri
                    - $uri/
                    - /index.php$is_args$args
                fastcgi: ''
                fastcgi_index: ''
                fastcgi_split_path: ''
                proxy: ''
                proxy_redirect: ''
            nxvl_cbzveeabsueo:
                location: '~ \.php$'
                autoindex: 'off'
                internal: 'false'
                try_files:
                    - $uri
                    - $uri/
                    - /index.php$is_args$args
                fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                fastcgi_index: index.php
                fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                fast_cgi_params_extra:
                    - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                    - 'APP_ENV dev'
                set:
                    - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                proxy: ''
                proxy_redirect: ''
  proxies: {  }
apache:
  install: '1'
  settings:
    user: www-data
    group: www-data
    default_vhost: true
    manage_user: false
    manage_group: false
    sendfile: 0
modules:
    - proxy_fcgi
    - rewrite
vhosts:
    av_cn9o84uc00lm:
        servername: ecoopony.dev
        docroot: /var/www/ecoopony
        port: '80'
        setenv:
            - 'APP_ENV dev'
        setenvif:
            - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
        custom_fragment: ''
        ssl: '1'
        ssl_cert: ''
        ssl_key: ''
        ssl_chain: ''
        ssl_certs_dir: ''
        ssl_protocol: ''
        ssl_cipher: ''
        directories:
            avd_5lx2ch1122oc:
                path: /var/www/ecoopony
                options:
                    - Indexes
                    - FollowSymlinks
                    - MultiViews
                allow_override:
                    - All
                require:
                    - 'all granted'
                custom_fragment: ''
                files_match:
                    avdfm_0aracx31omie:
                        path: \.php$
                        sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                        custom_fragment: ''
                        provider: filesmatch
                provider: directory
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '56'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_leq8n7vt488t:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
               group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    xdebug:
        install: '1'
        settings:
            xdebug.default_enable: '1'
            xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
            xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
            xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
            xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
            xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.19.0
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
   nodejs:
    install: '1'
    npm_packages: {  }
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
settings: {  }
server_ini:
    hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
    hhvm.server.port: '9000'
    hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
    hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
php_ini:
    display_errors: 'On'
    error_reporting: '-1'
    date.timezone: UTC
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '10.1'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
adminer: 0
users:
    mariadbnu_jxaavowwm7j6:
        name: dbuser
        password: '123'
databases:
    mariadbnd_vtlyt7388e5u:
        name: dbname
        sql: ''
grants:
    mariadbng_ts1rsb66mlu4:
        user: dbuser
        table: '*.*'
        privileges:
            - ALL
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.5'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
adminer: 0
users:
    mysqlnu_cbvogq12c8fp:
        name: dbuser
        password: dbuser
databases:
    mysqlnd_lhh6guehxdg1:
        name: ecoopony
        sql: ''
grants:
    mysqlng_y4rvv88xeu9t:
        user: dbuser
        table: '*.*'
        privileges:
            - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.4'
    server:
        postgres_password: '123'
databases: {  }
users: {  }
grants: {  }
adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
globals:
    version: 2.6.0
databases: {  }
redis:
install: '0'
settings:
    conf_port: '6379'
sqlite:
install: '0'
adminer: 0
databases: {  }
mailhog:
install: '1'
settings:
    smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
    smtp_port: 1025
    http_ip: 0.0.0.0
    http_port: '8025'
    path: /usr/local/bin/mailhog
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
     plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
settings:
    version: 2.1.0
    java_install: true
solr:
install: '0'
settings:
    version: 4.10.2
    port: '8984'
```

I am not sure if everything is ok with my ethernet adapters. I found that some people have problems with Bridge mode being disabled after Windows update. I've checked mines and they have 'VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver' ticked.

Here is output of ipconfig:

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5910:8995:2b70:f303%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::808:d5ee:2cdf:16f8%6
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4889:319:59b3:7241%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Not sure how they looked like before the update.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I had this problem as well, and none of the 5.x VB version fixes worked. I ended up downloading the latest 4.x version of VB from the "old downloads" section of Oracle's repository and that worked just fine with Win 10. I'd say that is going to be the most reliable workaround until VB is properly patched.

Comment: Thanks! So much time wasted.. and the solution was so simple! Downgrading indeed solved the issue. The weird thing is that before the upgrade I was quite sure I'd it working on 5.x.. I can resume work. I am happy. My client will be happy. Thanks Josh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with some newest Windows updates and VirtualBox 5.x indeed.
I've installed 4.3 and it helped. After restart it stopped working. VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver disappears from adapter settings. 
I was installing VB5. Driver comes back. I was checking it and then installing 4.3. After every restart I've needed to repeat those steps.

**Final resolution:**
Today I've checked the newest version 5.10.12 and it fixes bridge network issue in Windows 10. 
It seems to be much faster too.